# Laravel/Eloquent: Making archive list for posts (year, month)

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to create an archive list for a blog. I want something like this:

2020

- January (3)
- February (2)

2019

- January (10)
- February (23)

So far I've managed to get the posts sorted out in an array showing the count, however the array has each month as an array alone. I'd like it to be nested so that the year is the parent array and then each month is nested.

```
$posts_by_date = $blog->hasMany(Post::class)
  ->where('status', 'published')
  ->selectRaw('year(created_at) year, month(created_at) month, count(*) count')
  ->groupBy('year', 'month')
  ->orderByRaw('created_at') desc')
  ->get()
  ->toArray();
```

**Is there a way to make the group by nested instead of separate?** I know I can modify the results after, I just think it will be cleaner if I get this directly from the query.

Comment: If you're going to cast all of this to an array and use `selectRaw`, why don't you do an SQL query instead ? That'll be a lot easier for this kind of need.

Comment: @SteveChamaillard I've done it like this simply because I'm inexperienced with sql queries and Laravel. How would I do the sql query ? If you don't mind explaining :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collection::groupBy` which will group the elements by each value of the field specified, and so you will have a subarray for each year with inside the records that belongs to that year.
You just need to first `collect()` what you get in order to create a Collection, and then call `->groupBy('year')`.

Comment: This didn't work, I think because it doesn't return a collection ? I get the error: Undefined index: year.  But I tried collect($posts_by_date)->groupBy('year')->toArray();  underneath the initial code and that worked! So thanks :) If you edit your answer I'll accept it!

Comment: oh excellent, well it's actually really strange, on the documentation (https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasMany.html#method_get) there is Collection as return type, however i'll edit the answer